# Exploring Attributes in Google Ads API Beyond Official Documentation (Python)

Tags: python, ads, google-ads-api

I'm working with the Google Ads API, specifically with generating historical metrics as shown in this official documentation https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-historical-metrics.

I've encountered attributes in the API response, like month.month, which aren't directly mentioned in the documentation or given examples. Using `dir()` in Python to explore available attributes hasn't yielded the comprehensive results I expected.

```
# Example code snippet
for result in response.results:
    metrics = result.keyword_metrics
    for month in metrics.monthly_search_volumes:
        print(f'{month.month}')
```

How can I effectively discover and understand attributes that aren't immediately evident in the official documentation? Are there tools or methods that can help provide a deeper insight into available attributes within the Google Ads API responses?

Comment: The `month` attribute of the `MonthlySearchVolume` instances you are iterating over is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v15/MonthlySearchVolume).